# Работа в массивом

Tags: c#

Дан такой массив: как мне избавится от `foreach'ов` чтобы не писать их оч много а просто указать длинну строки?

```
string[] masiv = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        foreach (var it1 in masiv)
        {
            foreach (var it2 in masiv)
            {
                foreach (var it3 in masiv)
                {
                    foreach (var it4 in masiv)
                    {
                        foreach (var it5 in masiv)
                        {
                            string s = it1 + it2 + it3 + it4 + it5;
                            Console.WriteLine(s);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: эм... а что этот фрагмент должен делать? если перебор всех возможных комбинаций, то никак

Comment: @rdorn да, перебор простой,12345

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat<IEnumerable<string>>(new[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, 5).Aggregate((e, d)=>e.SelectMany(_=>d, string.Concat))`

Comment: @PetSerAl, это самое элегантное решение и заслуживает отдельного ответа. Полный пример: https://dotnetfiddle.net/H6Q8Kc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно по сути декартово произведение множества на себя. Как это сделать, описано, например, в [блоге Эрика Липперта](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/).

Воспользуемся вспомогательным классом оттуда:

```
static class CartesianExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
            this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        return sequences.Aggregate(emptyProduct, (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
    }
}
```

Имея этот класс, задача становится тривиальной:

```
string[] m = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
foreach (var s in (new[] { m, m, m, m, m }).CartesianProduct())
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(s));
```

Если хотите, `new[] { m, m, m, m, m }` можно заменить на `Enumerable.Repeat(m, 5)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    static IEnumerable<string> Combinations(int n)
    {
        if (n > 0)
        {
            foreach (var combination in Combinations(n - 1))
            {
                foreach (var e in masiv)
                {
                    yield return e + combination;
                }
            }
        }
        else yield return "";
    }
```

Рабочий пример: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dkiimp